# Can Facebook Crawl Multiple Pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm using `OpenGraph` with `Facebook` like buttons.

OG does not work properly until the pages have been crawled by Facebook.

Using the debug tool, I can force `Facebook` to crawl a specific page, but I have lots and lots of pages to be crawled.

Can `Facebook` follow pagination links to crawl these or is there another way to force `Facebook` to crawl these without having to manually enter them into the debug tool?

Answer (score 0):

when you type a url into facebook's debug tool, it uses this url format:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://example.com
```

so you would just need to write a script that makes a request for each url you need facebook to scrape.

Facebook will not automatically follow links for you, so writing a script to automate this process is probably your best approach.